# What is the difference between "not that X is going to Y" and "X is not going to Y"?

Tags: differences, negation, sentence-patterns

> - Not that running away is going to solve everything.
> - Running away is not going to solve everything.

I am not a native speaker. Is there a difference between the two?

Comment: What makes you think there *is* anything to "distinguish" here?

Comment: @FumbleFingers- How will he know unless he asks?

Answer (score 1):

> Not that running away is going to solve everything.

Usually this wording would absolve an implication that may have came about by the way a previous sentence was phrased. Usually I would say it if I think the person I am talking to assumes that because I don't think that "X" is bad then I must think that "X" is good.

> Running away is not going to solve everything.

This is a statement letting you know that running away will not solve everything.

So maybe the conversation goes.

> I can't really blame John for running away from home, not that running
>   away solves everything, but his parents hadn't let him eat for almost 3
>   days!